# Has anyone gotten Appium IDE to work with the Genymotion Android emulator?

Tags: android, appium, genymotion

I'm having all sorts of trouble getting Appium to work with the Genymotion emulator. I've worked with Appium and iOS extensively and without hassle, but getting setup with Android is quickly turning into a nightmare.

Does anyone have definitive steps on how to get Appium working with Genymotion? or any tips at least?

**Current Appium setup**

- Appium build: v1.3.0 (Beta) <= due to ios8
- App Path: is pointing to `app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk`
- Package: referenced from Android DDMS
- Platform Name: Android
- Automation Name: Appium
- Platform Version: 4.4 KitKat (API Level 19)
- Device Name: Android
- `Appium-doctor` is successful
- Launch does not return any errors
- Running Inspector initially throws: `error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT`
- Then Inspector looks successful: `[debug] Responding to client with success:`
- Then Inspector throws: `Could not start a new session`
- Relaunching Inspector then looks successful. Inspector opens and thumbnail view looks correct.
- **But Inspector does not show any selector paths**

[image]

- Changing `Context` does not appear to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using a relative path `app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk`. You need to use absolute path.